# Error deploying node.js app to Amazon Elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I recently deployed a new node.js app on beanstalk and keep running into the following error?

[Instance: i-cce89e4a] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 180, in npm_install raise e subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.4.6-linux-x64/bin/npm', '--production', 'rebuild']' returned non-zero exit status 254. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/pre/50npm.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

My version of node is: 4.4.7

The deployment seems to be failing at the last line below:

```
 except Exception, e:
            npm_debug_log = '/var/log/nodejs/npm-debug.log'
            app_npm_debug_log = os.path.join(app_path, "npm-debug.log")
            write_event('Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for more details.', 'ERROR')
            if not os.path.exists(app_npm_debug_log):
                utc_time_str = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("UTC %Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
                err_msg = str.format("{0} cannot find application npm debug log at {1} \n", utc_time_str, app_npm_debug_log)
                print(err_msg)
                with open(npm_debug_log, 'a') as f:
                    f.write(err_msg)
            else:
                shutil.copyfile(app_npm_debug_log, npm_debug_log)
            raise e
```

I cant seem to find any solid solution out there?

I manually zipped and uplaoded the files.

The app works perfectly locally.

Can anyone help?

```
Application deployment failed at 2016-07-09T18:47:38Z with exit status 1 and error: Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/50npm.sh failed.

+ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py --action npm-install
npm WARN package.json dashboard@0.0.2 No repository field.

> history@1.17.0 postinstall /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/history
> node ./npm-scripts/postinstall.js

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.14-24.50.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.4.6-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.4.6-linux-x64/bin/npm" "--production" "rebuild"
npm ERR! node v4.4.6
npm ERR! npm v2.15.5
npm ERR! path /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/gulp-main-bower-files/node_modules/main-bower-files/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/duplexify/node_modules/readable-stream/node_modules/unreachable-branch-transform/node_modules/recast/node_modules/esprima/bin/esvalidate.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/gulp-main-bower-files/node_modules/main-bower-files/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/duplexify/node_modules/readable-stream/node_modules/unreachable-branch-transform/node_modules/recast/node_modules/esprima/bin/esvalidate.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /tmp/deployment/application/npm-debug.log
Running npm install: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.4.6-linux-x64/bin/npm
Setting npm config jobs to 1
npm config jobs set to 1
Running npm with --production flag
Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for more details.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 695, in 
main()
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 677, in main
node_version_manager.run_npm_install(options.app_path)
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 136, in run_npm_install
self.npm_install(bin_path, self.config_manager.get_container_config('app_staging_dir'))
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 180, in npm_install
raise e
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.4.6-linux-x64/bin/npm', '--production', 'rebuild']' returned non-zero exit status 254.
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't have enough information to answer...
What does the /var/log/eb-activity.log say ?

...But
I encounter a similar error when running an npm install on a beanstalk with a t2.small : it had not enough RAM, npm failed. Upgrading to a bigger instance solve the problem. (commiting node_module could also solve this problem, but I didn't wanted to).

What you should do is connect with SSH to the instance, and watch with top/htop what is happening when deploying.

Comment: I upgraded to a medium instance.

Comment: actualy i spoke to soon - stil encountering the same error

Comment: Had the same issue and upgrading to higher memory instance fixed it.

Comment: To prevent this I'm now using docker based beanstalk, packaging node_modules in the docker with circle-ci

Answer (score 6):

After hours searching why the deploy fails. I can say that any of the following points could resolve the problem.

- Change nodejs version in the elacticbeanstalk configuration
- Change instance type from `t2.micro` to `t2.small` in the elacticbeanstalk configuration
- Set the new command that elasticbeanstalk will run when launch node application (according to your requirements) in the elacticbeanstalk configuration
- Or create a `.npmrc` file in root project with this content

```sh
# Force npm to run node-gyp also as root, preventing permission denied errors in AWS with npm@5
unsafe-perm=true
```

Comment: This worked for me! The npmrc file fixed my deployment.

Answer (score 4):

I was previously including my node_modules folder in my zip files. Excluding this folder resolved the problem

Answer (score 3):

If `npm install` is failing for you on a `nano` instance (e.g. `t3.nano`), another workaround is to enable swap memory for your instance by creating a file in your project `.ebextensions/swap.config` with the following contents:

```
commands:
    enable_swap_memory:
        command: "fallocate -l 1G /swapfile && chmod 600 /swapfile && mkswap /swapfile && swapon /swapfile"
        ignoreErrors: true
```

Then, try running `eb deploy` again and `npm install` should succeed.

Answer (score 0):

After running into continued npm install issues I decided to skip this step on Elastic Beanstalk and instead push my `node_modules` directory up along with built files from my CI env (Github Actions).

I used this module to install the correct Elastic Beanstalk config. The readme gives a good explanation of the problem:
https://github.com/mixmaxhq/eb-disable-npm

I had to add `!node_modules` to my `.ebignore` to ensure it's pushed. So far no EB errors and deploys are a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling S3 Bucket Versioning for codepipeline fixed the issue for me